# Getting user's current latitude/longitude

Tags: java, android, geolocation, locationmanager

I am trying to get the user's current latitude/longitude, using the following code :

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = (Location) lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

I keep getting the error that the methods getLatitude()/getLongitude() are undefined for the type **Location**.

How can I resolve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your imports to make sure you are importing android.location.Location and not something else.

Comment: I had somehow imported com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.Location, which was not letting me import android.location.Location, hence the error. Thanks so much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
```

add these two imports or if you are using eclipse simply press ctrl+shift+O and try

Comment: I had somehow imported com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.Location, which was not letting me import android.location.Location, hence the error. Thanks so much !!